# Why bind can't write(log) to file?

Tags: networking, permissions, dns, logging, bind

**SOLVED: adding /etc/bind/rndc.key solved the problem.**

U16.
I am configuring logging in my local master server.
Here's my *named.conf.options*:

```
logging {
    channel lan_channel {
        file "/var/log/named.log" versions 3 size 100m;
        print-time yes;
        print-category yes;
        print-severity yes;
        severity debug;
    };
    category general {
        lan_channel;
    };
};
```

Permissions on logging file:

```
-rwxrwxrwx 1 bind bind 0 Jan 16 15:32 /var/log/named.log
```

bind errs even on that world-writeable file.

```
systemctl restart bind9
systemctl status bind9 -l
... isc_stdio_open '/var/log/named.log' failed: permission denied
```

Would be grateful if someone shows how to solve the problem. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have the daemon chrooted? Selinux isn't active on ubuntu desktop, but if you are using a server with another distro I would check selinux permissions on that file.

Comment: Vanilla Ubuntu 16 LTS configuration without AppArmor touched and no Selinux. Bind is not chrooted.